# Why do ferromagnetic thermocouples change their behaviour near the Curie point?

Tags: condensed-matter, thermoelectricity

Having read Wikipedia's [current explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple#Type_K) that certain types of thermocouple (specifically Type K thermocouples) experience a step-change in their potential when they reach the Curie point of the constituent iron, it does not explain the reason, nor why the Curie point is important for the thermoelectric properties of ferromagnets. There seems to be no more of a hint on Wikipedia's page about [the thermoelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect), nor for the page on the Curie temperature. Searching the internet more generally for information only seems to find similar assertions without explanations, or abstracts from academic papers hidden behind paywalls.

Can anyone explain this connection in terms a layman reading Wikipedia would understand, or failing that an undergraduate physics student?